# In Blazor, how can I call a JS function from within a static C# method?

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor

In a razor file, I inject `@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime`. In the code behind, I invoke a JS function with the following code:

```
private async Task DownloadPdf(bool foo)
{
    await using var module = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./create-pdf.js");
    await module.InvokeVoidAsync("generatePdf", foo);
}
```

This works well but now I need to call a JS function from C# code that is not code behind but a separate *.cs file:

```
public static class Bar
{
    public static double Baz()
    {
        // do something
        // call JS function
        return baz;
    }
}
```

I tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59291254/how-to-inject-in-blazor-code-behind-razor-cs-file-ijsruntime-for-example) but `JSRuntime` is always `null`.
How can I invoke JS from my static C# method?

Comment: Not using `static` members - unless you add an `IJSRuntime` method parameter.

Comment: But `Bar` is `static` and if possible, I'd like to keep it `static`. What do you mean with adding an "`IJSRuntime` method parameter"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Assuming that `Baz` will always be a `static` method then you will need to pass in the `IJSRuntime` object into `Bar.Baz`.

  - **Do not** be tempted to pass `IJSRuntime` via a `static` field or property on `class Bar`: this will break your application as `static` data is shared by all threads.
- Also, seeming as `IJSRuntime.InvokeAsync` is a `Task`-returning `async` method, you will need to make `Bar.Baz` similarly also async.

Like so:

```
public static class Bar
{
    public static async Task<Double> BazAsync( IJSRuntime js, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default )
    {
        if( js is null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(js));

        // do something

        // call JS function:
        _ = await js.InvokeAsync<TReturnValue>( identifier: "someFunction", cancellationToken, args: new Object[] { "abc", 123 } );


        // return
        Double baz = 123.45d;
        return baz;
    }
}
```

Then you can call it from your Blazor code-behind class like so:

```
public partial class MyCodeBehindClass
{
    [Inject]
    IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

    private async Task DoSomethingAsync()
    {
        Double baz = await Bar.BazAsync( this.JSRuntime );
    }
}
```

Comment: In a further *.cs file with static class there is a property `public static bool Xyz`. In the setter I need `Bar.BazAsync(this.JSRuntime)` but what is `this.JSRuntime`?

Comment: @Flippowitsch `this.JSRuntime` is the `[Injected] IJSRuntime JSRuntime` in your code-behind.

Comment: @Flippowitsch You cannot invoke `async` methods in property getters nor setters. You need to reconsider your software-design.

Comment: But the further *.cs file is also separate and not a code behind file. OK agreed, I must reconsider. But is it really this complicated to invoke a JS function? Is there another option?

Comment: @Flippowitsch _"But is it really this complicated to invoke a JS function?"_ - **yes** - think carefully about the sheer amount of voodoo that goes on inside Blazor.

Comment: OK. Could you please help with what `this.JSRuntime` is in C# that is not code behind?

Comment: @Flippowitsch I already told you that `this.JSRuntime` is the `[Injected] IJSRuntime JSRuntime` in your code-behind. To use that `IJSRuntime` object instance elsewhere in your application (i.e. in other classes) you need to pass it as a method parameter (_from_ your code-behind class to whereever it's needed), like how `BazAsync` above has the `IJSRuntime js` parameter.